# Installing CentOS on remote machine?

Tags: linux, installation, remote, centos

Can I do a fresh install of CentOS Linux on a remote machine?

I have a machine with Windows NT in a remote location. Now I want to use that system as my deployment machine. To proceed with my plan I need to install a Linux OS (have chosen CentOS). The guy there with the machine is not very knowledgeable of the installation process of any OS.  So I thought I could install CentOS remotely.

Can you give me some insight on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [***kickstart installations***](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-whatis.html).  Kickstart is an automated installation method for RedHat-based distributions.  You [create a kickstart file](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/ch-redhat-config-kickstart.html) that describes the install options you want.  You'll have to configure a network installation or [roll-your-own install CD](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s2-kickstart2-boot-media.html), but with Kickstart all you'd do is mail a DVD to the guy in the server room and have him boot the CD.  He might have to type in a [particular boot command](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html), but if you set it up right the rest will be automated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the remote guy isn't very familiar with Linux, your best bet would be to send him a working CentOS install. If you are within a reachable geographical location, you could install CentOS into an existing machine and then post the harddisk over to the remote guy who can then just replace into the NT machine.

If the remote location is truly far away, you can send over a disk image on a DVD and have him `rawrite` the disk image onto the existing NT harddisk overwriting all contents. Alternatively, you could upload the image somewhere and have the remote guy download it to his machine.